# jQuery UI Datepicker won't render second month in restricted selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4w846rf3/

Where I am passing an array of dates to jQuery UI's datepicker. With those dates, I want to restrict the current calendar so that ONLY the dates provided can be selected. After much research I have found that the `beforeShowDay` function will help with restricting days, but what I'm experiencing is not correct. The current month's days will render the correct restricted days, but the next month will not.

```
var availableDates = [
    "12-22-2014", 
    "12-13-2014", 
    "12-27-2014", 
    "01-17-2015", 
    "01-24-2015"
];

function available(date) {
  dmy =  (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, availableDates)));
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "","Available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
  }
}

$('input').datepicker({beforeShowDay: available})
```

Renders December correctly:

[image]

and January incorrectly:

[image]

Comment: Look at your console.log output. `1-17-2015` is not the same as `01-17-2015`.

Comment: I suggest you make use of `$.datepicker.formatDate()` instead of concatenating numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var availableDates = [
  "12-22-2014", 
  "12-13-2014", 
  "12-27-2014", 
  "01-17-2015", 
  "01-24-2015"
];

function checkAvailability(date){
  var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
  return [availableDates.indexOf(dateString) !== -1]
}

$('input').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
});
```

As Barmar suggests, this takes advantage of `$.datepicker.formatDate()`, which as the name implies formats a date into a string value with a specified format.

Once we have a date string which is formatted in the same way as those in your array, it is a simple matter of using the `beforeShowDay` option, from which you only return true if the date string matches one of the ones you have specified.

The formatDate() method is one of the datepicker's utility functions.
You can read up on it here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-functions

**Demo**:

```js
var availableDates = [
  "12-22-2014", 
  "12-13-2014", 
  "12-27-2014", 
  "01-17-2015", 
  "01-24-2015"
];

function checkAvailability(date){
  var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
  return [availableDates.indexOf(dateString) !== -1]
}

$('input').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<input type="text"/>
```